# Check for multiple values in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 1 list with filenames and 1 nested list with filter words in it. The filter list has 3 lists with each different lenghts of sublists.

How can I iterate over the lists and use the `and` function? It needs to check all the values in the list because of the difference of `['employer', 'finance']` and `['employer', 'adress']`.

```
filter = [
    ['employer','finance'],
    ['manifest'],
    ['epmloyer','adress','home']
]

file_list = [
    '01012017_employer_finance.txt',
    '25102017_cargo_manifest.txt',
    '12022014_employer_finance.txt',
    '12022018_epmloyer_home_adress.txt',
    '12032016_employer_home_adress.rtx'
    ]

"""search for financial file"""
if filter[0][0] in file_list[0] and filter[0][1] in file_list[0]:
    print('Financial file found')

"""search for cargo manifest"""
if filter[1][0] in file_list[1]:
    print('Cargo manifest found')

"""search for adress file"""
if filter[2][0] in file_list[2] and filter[2][1] in file_list[2] and filter[2][2] in file_list[2]:
    print('Financial file found')
```

So far i managed to get the code below. But how do i take care of different lenghts of lists? and the use of variable for example: `filter[x][z]` in stead of `filter[1][0]`

```
"""loop through the file_list"""
for file in file_list:
    print("Identify file:", file)

    #identify file in list with lists in it

    if filter[0][0] in file and filter[0][1] in file:
        print('***Financial file found')
```

Ok i used the code given.

```
file_list = [
    '01012007-1_employer_finance.txt',
    '25102013-2_cargo_manifest.txt',
    '12022018-3_epmloyer_home_adress.txt',
    '12022028-4_epmloyer_work_adress.txt',
    '01012011-5_employer_finance.txt'
    '01012007-12_employer_finance.txt',
    '25102013-23_cargo_manifest.txt',
    '12022018-34_epmloyer_home_adress.txt',
    '12022028-45_epmloyer_work_adress.txt',
    '01012011-56_employer_finance.txt'
    ]

"""Dictionary files"""
filters = {
    'finance': ['employer','finance'],
    'manifest': ['manifest'],
    'address': ['epmloyer', 'adress', 'home'],
    'addres': ['epmloyer', 'adress', 'work']
}

"""Tweede oplossing op stackoverflow"""
"""Loop through the nested list"""

def matches(filter, filename):
    return all(x in filename for x in filter)

def get_filename(filter, files):
    for f in files:
        if matches(filter, f):
            return f

for label, filter in filters.items():
    file = get_filename(filter, file_list)
    if file:
        #print(f'Found {label} file: {file}')
        pass

found_files = {label: get_filename(filters, file_list) for label, filters in filters.items()}

print(found_files)
```

The result is:

```
{'finance': '01012007-1_employer_finance.txt', 'manifest': '25102013-2_cargo_manifest.txt', 'address': '12022018-3_epmloyer_home_adress.txt', 'addres': '12022028-4_epmloyer_work_adress.txt'}
```

However the list should be greater.

Comment: There are lots of files that needs to be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `all` function can be used to check the elements of a filter against a file name:

```
def matches(filter, filename):
    return all(x in filename for x in filter)
```

To find the file that matches a given filter, you'd iterate through the list of files and apply `match` to each item:

```
def get_filename(filter, files):
    for f in files:
        if matches(filter, f)
            return f
```

This can be expressed in an even shorter manner using the `next` function:

```
def get_filename(filter, files):
    return next((f for f in files if matches(filter, f)), None)
```

Calling `next` with a second argument makes it return `None` instead of raising an error when there are no matching files.

Now you can check for all the files. I'd recommend going a step further and labeling your filters using a dictionary:

```
filters = {
    'finance': ['employer','finance'],
    'manifest': ['manifest'],
    'address': ['epmloyer', 'adress', 'home'],
}

for label, filter in filters.items():
    file = get_filename(filter, files)
    if file:
        print(f'Found {label} file: {file}')
```

You can go even further and create a dictionary of the files you found:

```
found_files = {label: get_filename(filter, files) for label, filter in filters.items()}
```

Comment: When i have more files.
The output is still 3 lines (same amount of the filter)

Comment: @BearHunt. This only searches for the files you tell it to search for. It doesn't automatically find files you don't have a filter for.

Comment: i used your code. However wont give me all the files.

Comment: @BearHunt. I don't know how you used it or what went wrong, but A) there are some apparent typos in your filters, and B) feel free to ask another question and ping me when you do. I'll be happy to take a look at any clearly stated problem you present.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `any` and `all` with a generator expression that iterates through the keyword lists in the `filter` list:

```
for file in file_list:
    if any(all(keyword for keyword in keywords) for keywords in filter):
        print('***Financial file found')
```

Comment: Is it possible to acces the filterlist when you are in this loop? 
for example i want to extract the last item of the list where the key words are found?